# Is there such a thing as a PCI-e low profile gigabit NIC?

Tags: networking, computer-building, pci-express

I can't seem to find one anywhere.

**1. Is there a reason for this?** 
I would think most modern computers are both getting smaller and getting more moved over to PCI-e so that seems odd.

**2. Does anyone know where to find one?**

This is going into a Dell so that we can have TWO NIC cards. (on board and this new one) The Dell does NOT have any PCI slots and is in need of low profile cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this? http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166019

While it doesn't specifically list "low profile" in the specifications, this card (and many others) **does** include a low profile bracket that you can swap with the full-sized one on the same card.

Comment: While it doesn't say "low profile" the full-height fascia plate should be able to be swapped with a low-profile one.

Comment: It's not low profile. Would everything still line up if I switched the plate? CAN I even switch out that plate? How would I do that?

Comment: It comes with a low profile plate. Check out the last picture.

Comment: OK cool, I don't know why they wouldn't list that in specifications as another selling point. I almost didn't buy Intel because of it. Thank you!

Comment: Almost all cards of any sort that CAN be made low profile these days do come with a swappable backplate.  You see this a lot with smaller video cards, too.  It's so common I don't think they bother mentioning it sometimes, and it saves them from selling two versions of the same card.